# How to override drawable for certain API level only

Tags: android

Previously, I have a button, which its background is using `?attr/actionBarItemBackground` (`?attr/actionBarItemBackground` is from Android system itself)

```
<Button
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:text="1" />
```

---

For API level 21 and above, I would like it to have slightly different draw-able. Hence, I did the following modification.

```
<Button
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/keypadBackground"
    android:text="1" />
```

### drawable-v21/keypad_background_light.xml (Override)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
    android:radius="40dp" />
```

### drawable/keypad_background_light.xml (Tend no to override. But failed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="?attr/actionBarItemBackground" />
```

### styles.xml

```
<item name="keypadBackground">@drawable/keypad_background_light</item>
```

However, when I run on API 12, I get the following error message.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/keypad_background_light.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800c7
```

Comment: have you tried using `android:background="@drawable/keypad_background_light"`?

Comment: Tried. Same error.